# Transforming colors using a linear transformation

Tags: color

I want to transform all colors of a specific block according to some linear operation on the rgb color vector (or a representation in any other format if that's more convenient).
The transformation would be something like C' = A * C, where C was the original color (3-vector (r,g,b)), C' is the new color (r',g',b') and A is a 3x3 matrix describing the transformation.

The `xcolor` package has some commands that can be used to transform all colors used in a block, which is close to what I want. The transformations are too limited for my case though.
There is `\selectcolormodel{gray}` to transform all colors to grayscale, and there is `\maskcolors[<num model>]{<color>}` which allows only for scaling of the components by some constants.

Here these methods are shown in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{red}{red} \colorbox{blue}{blue} \colorbox{green}{green}

{\selectcolormodel{gray}
    \colorbox{red}{red} \colorbox{blue}{blue} \colorbox{green}{green}
}

{\maskcolors[cmyk]{magenta}
    \colorbox{red}{red} \colorbox{blue}{blue} \colorbox{green}{green}
}

\end{document}
```

I'm having a few ideas of how to achieve my desired result:

- Define a color model that does what I describe if I use `\selectcolormodel{mymodel}`. This is probably possible, but might be exceedingly complex.
- Redefine the `\color` command to change the color the way I want. This might not be general enough, but might be easier to achieve.

Before I dive into how to do these options, I wanted to check if there is an easier solution that I overlooked.

Comment: Welcome. // If you only need one or a few color transformations, perform them outside of Latex (e.g. on paper, by Excel, by a paint-tool etc.) and just define colors with those results.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the transformation to work for arbitrary colors